correlation between a random variable and a linear combination
Given random variables $X, Y$, and $Z$ with $\operatorname{corr}(X, Z) = a$, $\operatorname{corr}(Y, Z) = b$, $\operatorname{corr}(X, Y) = c$. Find the linear combination of $X$ and $Y$ that maximizes the correlation between itself and $Z$.
Namely, please solve:
$$\max_{\rho} \operatorname{corr}(X + \rho \cdot Y, Z)$$
I tried to set $f'(\rho) = 0$: $$\frac{b \sigma_Y (\sigma_X^2 + 2\rho c \sigma_X \sigma_Y + \rho^2 \sigma_Y^2) - (a \sigma_X + \rho b \sigma_Y)(c \sigma_X \sigma_Y + \rho \sigma_Y^2)}{(\sigma_X^2 + 2\rho c \sigma_X \sigma_Y + \rho^2 \sigma_Y^2)^{3/2}} = 0$$
and got $\rho = \frac{(b- a c) \sigma_X^2 \sigma_Y}{(a - bc) \sigma_X \sigma_Y^2}
$but don't know how to push forward.
Also I'm thinking about whether we can use some sort of projection to geometrically solve the problem but can't get my head around.

Since we are dealing with correlation and not covariance, without loss of generality we can assume that the variances of $X,Y,Z$ are one. The variance of $X+\rho Y$ is $1+2\rho c+\rho ^2=(\rho+c)^2+{1-c^2}$ and one wants to maximize
$$f(\rho)=E\left(\frac{X+\rho Y}{(1+2\rho c+\rho ^2)^{1/2}}Z\right)=\frac{a+b\rho}{(1+2\rho c+\rho ^2)^{1/2}}.$$ Denoting $\tan t=\frac{\rho+c}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}$ we get
$f(\rho)=A\cos t+b\sin t$ with $A=\frac{a-bc}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}.$
Observe that the determinant of the covariance matrix is $1+2abc-a^2-b^2-c^2$ and is positive. This permits to check that $A^2+b^2<1.$
Finally analyzing the maximum of $f$ and discussing the four cases of the sign of $A$ and $b,$ I find that the maximum of $f$ is $\sqrt{A^2+b^2}.$

I'm a bit confused. If you just set the variances to 1, according to my calculation related to the derivatives, shouldn't the answer just be (b-ac)/(a-bc)?

Indeed I did a supid mistake since $c\neq 0.$ You can keep however the idea that all the variances of $X,Y,Z$ can be taken as 1. Iam deleting my answer and will write later.

Emma, I don't understand what you ask for.

Sorry I didn't make it clear. I mean this problem is asking for $\rho$ instead of the maximum.

It is useful to examine the two limits $\rho=0$ and $\rho \gg 1$. In the first case $\operatorname{corr}(X+\rho Y, Z) = \operatorname{corr}(X,Z) = a$, and in the second case $\operatorname{corr}(X+\rho Y, Z) = \operatorname{corr}(Y,Z) = b$. I am not proving it, but I suspect that for $0 < \rho < \infty$, $\operatorname{corr}(X+\rho Y, Z)$ is between $\min(a,b)$ and $\max(a,b)$. Therefore $\rho = 0$ if $a > b$ and $\rho \to \infty$ if $b > a$.
(I am posting this as an answer as I do not enough reputation to post comments yet)

Interesting idea! But I think you assume that $X,Y$ are on the same side of $Z$(seeing the correlation as cos). But they may on the different side of $Z$ so there's a $\rho$ which can make $X+\rho Y$ collinear with $Z$.
